# Check if cookie does NOT contain specified content NGINX

Tags: nginx, configuration, config, vhosts

There are countless tutorials on checking if a cookie exists and contains my content, in this case `foobar`.

How do I do the following assuming mycookie is the cookie that I want set.

```
if ($cookie_mycookie does not equal "foobar") {
  return 401;
}
```

I have tried the following to no avail.

```
if (!$http_mycookie ~* "foorbar" ) {
  return 401;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Nginx, each cookie is available in embedded variable `$cookie_CookieName`. In case you want to check cookie with name `mycookie`, you can do it using this configuration snippet:

```
if ($cookie_mycookie != "foobar") {
  return 401;
}
```

From nginx [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for the `if` command:

> A condition maybe (among others):
>
> - Comparison of a variable with a string using the `=` and `!=` operators;
> - Matching of a variable against a regular expression using the `~` (for case-sensitive matching) and `~*` (for case-insensitive matching) operators.
> - Regular expressions can contain captures that are made available for later reuse in the $1..$9 variables.
> - Negative operators `!~` and `!~*` are also available. If a regular expression includes the `}` or `;` characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.